# Plotting a 3d Function using Meshgrid and Surfc

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

I know this seems like a basic question—and it probably is. I am having trouble learning how to plot this function using meshgrid and surfc. I keep getting the error saying that "The surface Z must contain more than one row or column." Why am I getting this error? Here's what I have to do:

[image]

```
x = 0:.01:1;
y = 0:.01:1;

f = @(x, y) sin(4*pi.*x).*sin(y).*(1-y) + (1./sqrt(1+10.*(x.^2)+ 100.*(y-0.5).^2))
Z = f(x, y);

[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y)
surfc(X, Y, Z)
```

Comment: Well, sounds like `surfc` is complaining about the size of `Z`. Check the sizes of `X`, `Y`, and `Z` using `size()`. Are they what you expect? And does that match the description of Z in `help surfc`?

Comment: X and Y are both 101 by 101. These make sense b/c I am using a meshgrid. However, Z is 1 by 101. This doesn't make sense since Z is suppose to be a 3d surface evaluated at 101 by 101 points. If this is correct, how do I figure out a way to get Z to be 101 by 101?

Comment: Take a close look at the `x` and `y` you're passing to the `f()` call. Are they also what you're expecting to be passing there, especially with respect to the `meshgrid` call? (Matlab is case sensitive.)

Comment: Ok thanks, got it. it should be f(X, Y) and the line Z = f(X, Y) should be moved below the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
x = 0:.01:1;
y = 0:.01:1;

f = @(x, y) sin(4*pi.*x).*sin(y).*(1-y) + (1./sqrt(1+10.*(x.^2)+ 100.*(y-0.5).^2))


[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y);

size(x)
size(Y)
size(Z)
surfc(X, Y, Z)
```